# I still have access to normal urls when rewrite urls is active

Tags: url-rewrite

I have **"URL Rewrite"** active, and now I have access to URLs like "catalog/product/view/id/719/s/p-product1/" but I also have access to rewritten URL '/p-product1/'

**how can I disable the normal URLs?**

Comment: It’s normal to always have access to the system url. However, make sure you have canonical urls turned on so google doesn’t ding you for duplicate content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the normal and intended way that Magento works. The `rewrite` URL will be use for SEO and regular navigation purposes.

You can look at [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64000/block-access-to-system-urls-through-htaccess-or-some-other-way) to get more info about other steps you can take.